# Move caret after a MoveFocus() call

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox, focus

I am attempting to manually control traversal of a number of `TextBox`es in a (WPF) Window. I am successfully using (this is within a PreviewKeyDown handler):

```
if (<logic>)
{
    ((TextBox)e.Source).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

to get the actual input point to the next TextBox, but the caret remains in the original TextBox until I type another character. How can I get it over immediately?  I have tried calling `nextTextBox.Focus()` and `Keyboard.Focus(nextTextBox)` but those don't work.

Comment: Never move the mouse cursor, nothing that pretty when the user keeps running off the mouse pad or the desk trying to move it back.  If you meant the blinking bar in the text box, that's called "caret".

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I meant Caret. I changed the wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! The call to `MoveFocus` must be in the `TextChanged` handler for the caret to move.